# failing to open my app after changing proxy

Tags: android, jmeter

I want to do performance testing of an android app.For this, I need to set manual proxy with a port.But, when I change the proxy with some port number (like 8181 or 8282) I not able to open the app.If I opened also not able the send the request of that app to the app server.

How to solve this problem.

Comment: `I not able to open the app` what exactly happens?

Comment: It show unfortunately, [App Name] has stopped with proxy 8181.Than I tried with 8282.In this case, I am able to open the app.But in that app I need to send request to app server that I am not able to send.

Comment: then look at the logcat to see the cause of the exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tags, it seems you are trying to script a test scenario using JMeter. You mentioned that the app stopped working after setting the proxy. Could you confirm that you had started the JMeter proxy before changing your proxy settings?

You can have a look at this document for step-by-step instructions on setting up JMeter proxy-
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

If you are using the latest version of JMeter, there will slight differences in the options, but overall instructions should help you get started.

Comment: Here I am talking about mobile app not the web application.